# iOS view similar to Chronometer on Android

Tags: android, ios, view, chronometer

On Android there exists a standard view called Chronometer [details here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html). Does iOS have a similar view or a library that does something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I not found anyway todo this, so i create a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/4155970) with GPL license, if someone get excited to make it a lib :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `Timer` for this.

```
var timer = Timer()
timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    startTime = Date() // new instance variable that you would need to add.
}

func update() {
    let elapsedTime = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
    let currTime = totalTime - elapsedTime
    //total time is an instance variable that is the total amount of time in seconds that you want
    countDown.text = String(currTime)
    if currTime < 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
        //do other stuff that you need to do when time runs out.
    }
}
```

If you want a smaller or larger pieces of time, just change it the `Interval` parameter.
Also you still would have to address creating some logic to split minutes / seconds ect. using `Date` methods and incrementing some instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [UIDatePicker](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) in timer mode?

```
UIDatePicker* datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 206)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
datePicker.countDownDuration = 60*5;
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];
```

Comment: UIDatePicker looks very different from what I need, if I can leave it with appearance similar this http://cdn5.staztic.com/cdn/screenshot/simplechronometer-2-0.jpg could be.